# Comparing all structure items with specific rules

Tags: c, conditional-statements

I have a structure with 4 items inside.

```
typedef struct
    {
    char colour;
    char shape;
    char nr;
    char p;
    }CARDS;
```

This structure has many items inside and I want to compare them 3 by 3.. 
so compare for example cards[1], cards[2],cards[3]. 
If 3/4 of the elements between the 3 cards are equal then we have a SET so **set=1**. 
If no elements are equal we again have **set=1**.

For sure I could just write many If

```
If (cards[1].colour=cards[2].colour=cards[3].colour)
    counter = counter +1;
If (cards[1].shape=cards[2].shape=cards[3].shape)
    counter=counter+1;
If (cards[1].nr=cards[2].nr=cards[3].nr)
    counter=counter+1;
If (cards[1].p=cards[2].p=cards[3].p)
    counter=counter+1;
```

and then make an if statement for counter

```
 If (counter==3||counter==0)
     set=1;
```

Is there any other more elegant way to do it?

Comment: @e0k also OP is doing if (a = b = c)` so there's a lot going on here.

Comment: You probably also mean `if` rather than `If` - please post actual code, not a rough approximation.

Comment: The examples appear to be pseudocode of some kind

Comment: If you post with the [tag:c] tag, please use C for your examples.

Comment: Well my full code is about 500 lines, I don't want to confuse you more, so yes it is not the actual code, that's why i post just the part that i have a problem, simplified..ANd the code is written in c

Comment: Can "cards" array can have more that 3 cards?

Comment: that posted code for the 'many ifs' are actually assignments, not comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

First off you are using `=` when you should be using `==`, compile with warnings to see this.  You are also attempting to compare three things at once. You can't do `if (a == b == c)` but must instead do `if (a == b && a == c)` or similar.

A true `==` result is equal to `1` and you can use that here by just adding it up:

```
int count = 
    (cards[1].colour == cards[2].colour && cards[1].colour == cards[3].colour)
    + (cards[1].shape == cards[2].shape && cards[1].shape == cards[3].shape)
    + (cards[1].nr == cards[2].nr && cards[1].nr == cards[3].nr)
    + (cards[1].p == cards[2].p && cards[1].p == cards[3].p);

int set = count == 3 || count == 0;
```

Comment: It should be int set = count >= 3 || count == 0;

Comment: @bunty that would make sense to be for a card game but it's not what OP describes in "code" or in english above

Comment: It is clearly mentioned "If 3/4 of the elements between the 3 cards are equal then" means if 3 or 4 elements (colour, shape nr, p) are equal then we have a SET so set=1. The condition "count == 3" will become false if all 4 elements are equal.

Comment: @bunty, 3/4 != 4/4. OP's condition is `counter==3||counter==0`

Answer (score 0):

You could make your data structure more amenable to this kind of comparison, e.g.

```
typedef enum {
    COLOUR,
    SHAPE,
    NR,
    P,
    NUM_ATTRS
} ATTRS;

typedef struct {
    char attrs[NUM_ATTRS];
} CARD;
```

This enables you to use simple loops to test multiple attributes of multiple cards, rather than hard-coded explicit logic.

Answer (score 0):

There is a serious bug in the condition, there should be a *greater than*: If 3/4 of the elements between the 3 cards

```
if (counter >= 3 || counter==0)
     set=1;
```